# Trying to popup a panel in Java

Tags: java

Okay, i don't want to use other 3rd party libraries right now. Trying to make own stuff.

You guys know how the date control in Windows is/was? Looked like a plain textbox with a button next to it and on clicking a button, a new smaller window/calendar opened to select dates. This window does not shove off the other controls...it is like on top of all of them.

I am trying to do the same in Java. I could only get so far....

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class PopupPanelDemo{
public static void main(String ags[]){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Date");
    JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JButton b =  new JButton("Show");

    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black,1));
    p.setBackground(Color.red);
    p.setVisible(false);

    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.add(l);
    f.add(t);
    f.add(b);
    f.add(p);

    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            p.setSize(t.getWidth(), t.getHeight());
            p.setLocation(t.getLocation().x, t.getLocation().y + t.getHeight());
            p.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

I have not got it to work properly. The JPanel displays correctly, as intended in the code only when i click the button twice.

Is there a HTML like zindex stuff in java?

Is this the right route or is there some other control that i should check?

PS. The JPanel will be substituted by my calendar panel. I just included the necessary stuff here.

I am using Window 8.1 and Java 1.8.0_45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use a PopupFactory (like swing does to show tooltips and menus):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

class PopupPanelDemo {
    public static void main(String ags[]) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Date");
        JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JButton b = new JButton("Show");

        p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
        p.setBackground(Color.red);
        p.add(new JLabel("Test"));

        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.add(l);
        f.add(t);
        f.add(b);

        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                PopupFactory pf = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
                p.setSize(t.getWidth(), t.getHeight());
                p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(t.getWidth(), t.getHeight()));
                Point l = t.getLocationOnScreen();
                Popup popup = pf.getPopup(f, p, l.x, l.y + t.getHeight());
                popup.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```